# set cookie in jquery for show/hide div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a CSS menu in a div that is set with CSS: display:none; on page load.

I have this html:

```
<a class="show_menu">Show Menu</a>
<a class="hide_menu" style="display:none;">Hide Menu</a>

<div id="nav" style="display:none;">
div content here
</div
```

and this JQUERY:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$('.show_menu').click(function() {
   $('#nav').toggle();
   $("#page_cont").css("width", "80%");
   $(".hide_menu").css("display", "block");
   $(".show_menu").css("display", "none");
});
$('.hide_menu').click(function() {
   $('#nav').toggle();
   $("#page_cont").css("width", "100%");
   $(".hide_menu").css("display", "none");
   $(".show_menu").css("display", "block");
});
</script>
```

What would be the best way to see a cookie when the div is shown or hidden so when the user changes the page, if they had the menu open it would stay open on another page and if they close the menu it would close on all other pages until they open it again?

EDIT: here is my new code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<script>
var menu_state = $.cookie('mydomain_menuflag');
alert(menu_state);
if(menu_state !== "undefined" && menu_state == "visible" ) $('#nav').show;
</script>

<div class="show_menu"><a>Show Menu</a></div>
<div class="hide_menu" style="display:none;"><a>Hide Menu</a></div>

<div id="nav" style="display:none;">
<li><a href="/admin/index.php">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a>Contacts</a>
    <ul>
    <li><strong>Companies</strong></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=customer/addcustomer">Add Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=customer/viewcustomer">View Company</a></li>
    <li><strong>Contacts</strong></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=contacts/addcontact">Add Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=contacts/viewcontact">View Contact</a></li>
    <li><strong>Resellers</strong></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=reseller/addreseller">Add Reseller</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=reseller/viewreseller">View Reseller</a></li>
    <li><strong>Salesman</strong></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=salesman/addsalesman">Add Salesman</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=salesman/viewsalesman">View Salesman</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a>Customer Info</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=customer/commsone-phonelines">Comms One Phone Lines</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$('.show_menu').click(function() {
   $('#nav').toggle();
   $("#page_cont").css("width", "80%");
   $(".hide_menu").css("display", "block");
   $(".show_menu").css("display", "none");
   $.cookie('mydomain_menuflag', 'visible');
   var menu_state = $.cookie('mydomain_menuflag');
   alert(menu_state);
});
$('.hide_menu').click(function() {
   $('#nav').toggle();
   $("#page_cont").css("width", "100%");
   $(".hide_menu").css("display", "none");
   $(".show_menu").css("display", "block");
   $.cookie('mydomain_menuflag', 'hidden');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this lib: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Set your cookie in your show event function:

```
$.cookie('mydomain_menuflag', 'visible');
```

and hide:

```
$.cookie('mydomain_menuflag', 'hidden');
```

and in document load do your initial check

```
var menu_state = $.cookie('mydomain_menuflag');
if( typeof menu_state !== "undefined" && menu_state == "visible" ) $('#nav').show;
```

I didn't test, so let me know if I left a bug in.

### Edit:

Here's the whole code that should do it:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {

  // setup the initial display on page load
  var menu_state = $.cookie('mydomain_menuflag');

  if( typeof menu_state !== "undefined" && menu_state == "visible" ) {
    $('#nav').show; // visible, and cookie is set
  } else {
    $('#nav').hide; // hidden or cookie is not set, set just in case
    $.cookie('mydomain_menuflag', 'hidden'); // update (or set) the cookie
  }

  // listen for the clicks
  $('.show_menu').click(function() {
     $('#nav').toggle();
     $.cookie('mydomain_menuflag', 'visible'); // update (or set) the cookie
     $("#page_cont").css("width", "80%");
     $(".hide_menu").css("display", "block");
     $(".show_menu").css("display", "none");
  });
  $('.hide_menu').click(function() {
     $('#nav').toggle();
     $.cookie('mydomain_menuflag', 'hidden'); // update (or set) the cookie
     $("#page_cont").css("width", "100%");
     $(".hide_menu").css("display", "none");
     $(".show_menu").css("display", "block");
  });

});

</script>
```

and add this line inside your head tag: `<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>`

I would generally recommend downloading and linking a local copy of the library, but the above should get you up and running to start with.

### Edit 2:

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YZenq/1/

NOTE: A JSFiddle is *not* the same as your web page.

1. The fiddle does not need a document ready as their code handles that. Your page should use that, but put all your code inside one, not multiple.
2. A fiddle does not let you change your document head ( `<head> ... </head>` ). The fiddles have an external resources option on the left to do the same thing as the library I provided the link to for you. On a fiddle you just put in the URL (ie. the code inside the src attribute of the script tag). But you will need to add the whole script tag, the smaller one that links to the library, just inside the end of your head tag.

Does that make sense?

### Edit 3:

Updated fiddle with change to stop it setting multiple cookie instances: http://jsfiddle.net/YZenq/2/

Comment: so i just put <script>
var menu_state = $.cookie('mydomain_menuflag');
if( typeof menu_state !== "undefined" && menu_state == "visible" ) $('#nav').show;
</script> under the <body> tag? and obviously add the other bits too

Comment: I would put the large script tag just inside your body tag. The small tag ( `<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>` ) needs to go inside your head tag. I don't believe you can do that on a fiddle. Edit: your fiddle is all messed up I'll see if I can sort it out for you.

Comment: ok - yeah i think so. do i put your JS code above or below my html? i have tried both but the div isnt changing when i click the link :/

Comment: if u open the div in the jsfiddle it doesnt save the cookie either

Comment: Yes, it is saving the cookies. I can see them in chrome under the site fiddle.jshell.net. Actually I'll make a slight change to make sure it doesn't add multiple cookies now that I see it's doing that. Anyway, how are you working on the page you're working on, because I keep referring to the `<head>` tag and you haven't indicated that you know what I'm talking about, so I'm wondering if you're trying to do this on some restricted service that's not letting you view/edit the entire html?

Comment: How can I use your method for my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674877/how-to-use-session-cookie-to-open-close-a-slide-in-div